# What kind of node use for Ethereum development?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, full-node

I am working with ethereum and to connect my backend to the blockchain I use an ethereum node: full node or a light node. I was asked a question but I didn't quite understand how to answer.
The question is: Suppose we are using a light node. If in the future I want to use a full node what changes at the interface level?

I know that a full node stores complete blockchain data and participates in block validation, verifies all blocks and states.
While a light node stores the header chain and not the entire blockchain.

Comment: I am using archival node because I need to test my custom EVM code on specific transactions at specific blocks. You can setup a cheap archival development node with an HDD and small SSD disk configured as `bcache` caching device. This way you can use a 8TB disk without buying all the 8TB in SSD storage

Comment: @Nulik Actually I did't understand very well the question that was asked to me. What changes at the interface level between a full node, a light node or an archive node?

Comment: I am not using light nodes, so I can't tell. Light nodes were designed for IOT devices so it is not my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want either.

You want a free Ethereum API node service like one from [CloudFlare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-ethereum-gateway/) or [others](https://ethereumnodes.com/).

Light nodes are not feasible for real applications, as they do not provide API services and data needed.